# Rewriting sine using simprocs in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I want to implement a simproc capable of rewriting the argument of sin into a linear combination x + k * pi + k' * pi / 2 (where ideally k' = 0 or k' = 1) and then apply existing lemmas about additions of arguments in sines.

The steps could be as follows:

1. Pattern match the goal to extract the argument of sin(expr):

```
fun dest_sine t =
      case t of
        (@{term "(sin):: real ⇒ real"} $ t') => t'
      | _ => raise TERM ("dest_sine", [t]) ;
```

2. Prove that for some x, k, k': expr = x + k*pi + k' * pi/2.
3. Use existing lemmas to rewrite to a simpler trigonometric function:

```
fun rewriter x k k' =
 if (k mod 2 = 0 andalso k' = 0) then @{term "sin"} $ x
 else if (k mod 2 = 0 andalso k' = 1) then @{term "cos"} $ x
 else if (k mod 2 = 1 andalso k' = 0) then @{term "-sin"} $ x
 else @{term "-cos"} $ x
```

I'm stuck at step two. The idea is to use algebra simplifications to obtain the x,k,k' where the theorem holds. I believe schematic goals should do this but I haven't ever used them.

**My thoughts**

Could I rather assume that the expression is of this form and let the simplifier find it so that the simproc can be triggered?

If I first start assuming the linear form x + k*pi + k' * pi/2 then:

1. Extract x,k,k' from this combination.
2. Apply rewriter and obtain the corresponding term to be rewritten two.
3. Apply in a sequence: rules dealing with + pi/2, rules dealing with + 2 pi

Comment: it is relevant to say that the theorem should be a boolean reflection of a logical proposition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start easy and ignore the `pi / 2` part for now.

You probably want to build a simproc that matches on anything of the form `sin x`. Then you want to write a *conversion* that takes that term `x` (which is assumed to be a sum of several terms) and brings it into the form `a + of_int b * p`.

A conversion is essentially a function of type `cterm → thm` which takes a cterm `ct` and returns a theorem of the form `ct ≡ …`, i.e. it's a form of deterministic rewriting (a conversion can also fail by throwing a `CTERM` exception, by convention). There are a lot of combinators for building and using these in `Pure/conv.ML`.

This is probably a bit fiddly. You essentially have to descend through the term and, for each atom (i.e. anything not of the form `_ + _`) you have to figure out whether it can be brought into the form `of_int … * pi` (e.g. again by writing a conversion that does this transformation – to make it easy you can omit this part so that your procedure only works if the terms are already in that form) and then group all the terms of the form `of_int … * pi` to the right and all the terms not of that form to the left using associativity and commutativity.

I would suggest this:

- Define a function `SIN_SIMPROC_ATOM x n = x + of_int n * pi`
- Write a conversion `sin_atom_conv` that rewrites `of_int n * pi` to `SIN_SIMPROC_ATOM 0 n` and everything else into `SIN_SIMPROC_ATOM x 0`
- Write a conversion that descends through `+`, applies `sin_atom_conv` to every atom, and then applies some kind of combination rule like `SIN_SIMPROC_ATOM x1 n1 + SIN_SIMPROC_ATOM x2 n2 = SIN_SIMPROC_ATOM (x1 + x2) (n1 + n2)`
- In the end, you have rewritten your entire form to the form `sin (SIN_SIMPROC_ATOM x n)`, and then you can apply some suitable rule to that.

It's not quite clear to me how to best handle the parity of `n`. You could rewrite `sin (SIN_SIMPROC_ATOM x n) = (-1) ^ nat ¦n¦ * sin x` but I'm not sure if that's what the user really wants in most cases. It might make more sense to only do that if you can deduce the parity of `n` statically (e.g. by using the simplifier) and then directly simplify to `sin x` or `-sin x`.

The situation becomes even more complicated if you want to include halves of π. You can of course extend `SIN_SIMPROC_ATOM` by a second term for halves of π (and one for doubles of π as well to make it more uniform). Or you could ad all of them together so that you just have a single integer `n` that describes your multiples of π/2, and `k` multiples of π simply contribute `2k` to that term. And then you have to figure out what `n mod 4` is – possibly again with the simplifier or with some clever static method.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: sorry, I think I was confused, I implemented SIN_SIMPROC_ATOM at the ML level, while I think it should be written in the user level and then write theorems in the ML level using that syntax...sorry, I erase my comments

Comment: It should be a definition in HOL. A fairly vacuous one, just to make things a bit easier to conceptualise. You could also do without it and simply build terms of the form `_  + of_int _ * pi` directly.

Comment: In either case, the idea is that you prove suitable combination theorems for these and then plug them together in ML.